# Brackets - DOM Agent Needs To Be Enabled First

Tags: adobe-brackets

Brackets live preview doesn't appear to be working correctly. Upon clicking live preview, the yellow lightening bolt icon is only half filled. The browser tries to start loading the live preview, however it is stuck on the brackets waiting... page.

The URL IS: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Brackets/www/LiveDevelopment/launch.html

I've opened up the brackets devtools (localhost:9234/devtools/devtools.html?ws=localhost:9234/devtools/page/ec744244d7ea99e5c99ffeb2ff42872e) to look for errors, and the browser console reads:

```
enable failed on agent css ErrorNotification.js:117

DOM agent needs to be enabled first. Object {code: -32000, message: "DOM agent needs to be enabled first."} 
Object {method: "CSS.enable", id: 6, params: Object} ErrorNotification.js:117

Assertion failed: Attempted to call remote method without objectId set. /LiveDevelopment/Agents/RemoteAgent.js:58

Some arguments of method 'Runtime.callFunctionOn' can't be processed

Parameter 'objectId' with type 'String' was not found. 

Object {code: -32602, message: "Some arguments of method 'Runtime.callFunctionOn' can't be processed", data: Array[1]}

Object {method: "Runtime.callFunctionOn", id: 7, params: Object}  ErrorNotification.js:117
Some arguments of method 'Runtime.callFunctionOn' can't be processed
Parameter 'objectId' with type 'String' was not found. 
Object {code: -32602, message: "Some arguments of method 'Runtime.callFunctionOn' can't be processed", data: Array[1]}

Object {method: "Runtime.callFunctionOn", id: 8, params: Object} ErrorNotification.js:117
```

I've Tried:

- Rebooting
- Uninstall / Reinstall
- Removing ALL plugins

I'm out of ideas. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Does this happen for _all_ projects, or only some? For example, if you open the default "Getting Started" project that comes with Brackets and run Live Preview there, does the same thing happen?

Comment: Also -- are you on Chrome stable, or on a different channel like dev or Canary?

Comment: @ytpete This happens for all projects, and is using a stable release of Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "DOM agent needs to be enabled first" issue was introduced with Chrome 40 (which is not yet stable), so fix for Brackets 1.0 and earlier is to use Chrome 39. There's a [pending fix](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/10088) for Chrome 40 for Brackets 1.1.

Comment: Apparently Chromium v41.0 still has the same issue, with Brackets Release 1.0, build 1.0.0-15191.

Comment: And, unless I'm mistaken, the 1.1.0-15396 also has that issue (so that's v1.1, prerelease).

Comment: You are correct. Accepted as correct answer. Thanks!